# How do you get a text from a span tag using BeautifulSoup when there's no clear identification?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-collection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrHf.png)

I am trying to extract the value from this span tag for Year Built using BeautifulSoup and  the following code below, but I'm not getting the actual Year. Please help. Thanks :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYmkR.png)

```
results = []
for url in All_product[:2]:
   link = url
   html = getAndParseURL(url)
   YearBuilt = html.findAll("span", {"class":"header font-color- 
   gray-light inline-block"})[4]
   results.append([YearBuilt])
```

The output shows

```
[[<span class="header font-color-gray-light inline-block">Year Built</span>],
[<span class="header font-color-gray-light inline-block">Community</span>]]
```

Comment: Please post code as formatted code in your question and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.next_sibling`:

```
result = []
year_built = html.find_all(
   "span", {"class":"header font-color- gray-light inline-block"}
)
for elem in year_built:
    if elem.text.strip() == 'Year Built':
        result.append(elem.next_sibling)
```

I'm not sure how the whole HTML looks, but something along these lines might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Sure there would be a more specific solution to extract all attributes for your results you may need, but therefor you should improve your question and add more details*

---

Using css selectors you can simply chain / combinate your selection to be more strict. In this case you select the `<span>` contains your string and use `adjacent sibling combinator` to get the next sibling `<span>`.

```
YearBuilt = e.text if (e := html.select_one('span.header:-soup-contains("Year Built") + span')) else None
```

It also avoid `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`, if element is not available you can check if it exists before calling text method

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

results = []
for url in All_product[:2]:
    link = url
    html = getAndParseURL(url)
    YearBuilt = e.text if (e := html.select_one('span.header:-soup-contains("Year Built") + span')) else None
    results.append([YearBuilt])
```